# Interpreting LED light strip data sheet

Tags: power-supply, led-strip

I'm trying to understand data sheets for flexible LED light strips.   I'm looking at https://www.inspiredled.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/12V-SB-White-Flex-Spec-2.2.pdf, for example.   It says:

> **To be installed in accordance with NEC, using Class 2 12V power supply only!**

At the bottom of the subsequent  table, it says:

| Power Source | Max Length |
| --- | --- |
| 150W Transformer | 1046.5” (135W) |

**Questions**

Is a class 2 power supply limited to 100VA?

I've mostly dealt with DC, so I've forgotten a lot about VAs, but I'm roughly equating VA to Watt.   Have I forgotten something important?

Wouldn't a 150W transformer power source violate the limits of Class 2?

Do strips like this do their own rectification so that they can be powered directly from a transformer?

Is using a switch-mode power supply rated `12V ⎓ 10A` Class 2?  Is it more efficient than a transformer?

Does a Class 2 power supply require a UL or other NRTL symbol to be used in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of the puzzle... from http://escventura.com/manuals/sola_introNECclass2_rg.pdf

[image]

This table, "Table 11(b)", is for DC power supplies. Table 11(a) has the requirements for AC transformers.

From that same tech note, "Not inherently limited" means...

> an additional protection device (usually a mechanical circuit breaker or
> fuse) protects against overload within a defined time. The additional protection device must be installed
> within or closely connected to the power source, so that it can be regarded as one unit.

and "inherently limited" means:

> that the power source itself limits the output current (e.g.: using a electronic or magnetic circuitry).

It would seem that the limits on the "Not inherently limited" kind refer to the power supply + additional protection device operating together.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference.   Data from a vendor like this seems much more reliable than most web sources.